# Gigya cdc sap accounts.register custom language

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

I am having a problem with the registration of the user and the lang parameter that is passed in the `accounts.register` call. `Gigya.js` is called with the custom language we set to `de_AT`, but in registration, language is set to `de`. Where is this language set when the registration form is submitted?

Comment: Forgot to mention this is hybris storefront implementation

Comment: Underscore isn't supported. Locales need to be in the format 'en-US' (with hyphen).
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/e45af179a1494d12b8252da07ded120b.html#add-a-locale

Answer (score 2):

Underscore isn't supported. Locales need to be in the format 'en-US' (with a hyphen; supported characters are latin alphabet, numbers, and hyphen).

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/e45af179a1494d12b8252da07ded120b.html#add-a-locale

Comment: Thanks. I tried with underscore and it works. Our hybris commerce using underscore and we dont want to change this. When register user we set profile local to de_AT cos we ne need that parameter back when email verification is done and redirection to correct store language must be shown. Even to screen sets localization we set de_AT and it works for now. We also put de_AT for consentments and set lang at rest api account register and login to our lang code. For now it works. Can we have any problems we are not aware of?